# hola, presento error al ejecutar cualquier archivo.py linux

Tags: python, linux

un codigo sencillo como print("hola") me presenta: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado
trabajo en linux mint
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para ejecutarlo justo como lo estás intentando te falta el shebang al inicio del archivo. Coloca algo como `#!/usr/bin/env python3` al inicio del archivo. Alternativamente simplemente usa `python3 1.py` en la terminal. (Todo esto suponiendo tienes python instalado en el sistema y accesible en el `Path` ).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: gracias esa era la soluciòn